# usercustomize.py loaded but ignored on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, startup

I am trying to define some functions at startup of the Python interpreter. After some digging I did the following:

`python3 -m site`

from that I get my user site directory which happens to be at:

`/Users/myusername/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages'`

I place a `usercustomize.py` file at this location, yet it doesn't seem to be executed.

This is the content of my file:

```
crazyvar = 100

import sys
```

When I launch python with `PYTHONVERBOSE` it seems like it's loading it.

```
# /Users/myusername/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/__pycache__/usercustomize.cpython-39.pyc matches /Users/myusername/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/usercustomize.py
# code object from '/Users/myusername/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/__pycache__/usercustomize.cpython-39.pyc'
import 'usercustomize' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x10f496a90>
```

but whenever I launch the interactive interpreter and try to query `crazyvar` or `sys.argv` I get  `NameError: name 'crazyvar' is not defined`

Any idea how I can get this to work??

Comment: It looks like the file is executed (I can print ```crazyvar``` or examine sys) but somehow gets unloaded. Not sure how I can make these  imports and variables persistent

Comment: I accomplished what I wanted using ```PYTHONSTARTUP``` apparently ```usercustomize.py``` is not used for that sort of thing. The documentation is lackluster  on the topic.